# has_many :through not creating my third model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, has-many-through, model-associations

I'm building a location based application, and noticed some strange behavior. My models are the following:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :attendances, dependent: :destroy
has_many :events, through: :attendances

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
acts_as_mappable :lat_column_name => :latitude,
                 :lng_column_name => :longitude

has_many :attendances, dependent: :destroy
has_many :users, through: :attendances

class Attendance < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :event
```

So the problem is, when creating new events, I first have `user.events.new(params)` and then I have an if statement that checks if new event was saved correctly or not, so `if event.save #do stuff.` When I do this, the `Attendance` model that connects `user` to the newly created `event` is not created, whereas if I have `user.events.create(params),` a new `Attendance` is successfully created. Is this normal? Do I have to use `user.events.create` in this case? And why isn't a new `Attendance` created when I do`user.events.new` then `event.save`?

EDIT: Added `Create` method from `events_controller.rb`:

```
def create
if params[:username] && params[:password]
  username = params[:username]
  password = params[:password]
  user = User.find_by(username: username)
  if user
    if user.authenticate(password)
      event_title = params[:title]
      event_date = Date.parse(params[:date])
      event_description = params[:description]
      latitude = params[:latitude]
      longitude = params[:longitude]
      event = user.events.new(title: event_title, date: event_date, description: event_description, latitude: latitude,
        longitude: longitude)
      if event.save
        render :json => {id: event.id, title: event.title, date: event.date, description: event.description, latitude: event.latitude,
          longitude: event.longitude
        }
      else
        error_message(event.errors.full_messages)
      end
      #attendance = Attendance.find_by(user_id: user.id, event_id: event.id)
      #attendance.update_attribute(:host, 1)
    else
      error_message("Authentication failed. Please login, or sign up.")
    end
  else
    error_message("Username not recognized. Make sure username is right, or sign up.")
  end
else
  not_found
end
end
```

Comment: can you show us the Event controller?

Comment: Sure. I'll edit and add the create method in my events controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behaviour is expected and it is a well known problem. Fortunately it has a solution. Try to add `inverse_of` parameter to your belongs_to associations:

```
class Attendance < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :attendances
  belongs_to :event, inverse_of: :attendances
end
```

You can read more about this problem here: [Link](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/13933)

**Solution 2:**

You can also change your controller code to this:

```
  event = Event.new(...event_params...)
  if event.save
    user.events << event
    render :json => {...}
  else
    ...
```

Comment: Say I use `inverse_of`, doesn't that mean a new `event` will be automatically created every time a new user is  created?

Comment: No, this option is used for other purposes. You can read more about it here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: You're right. I realized safari was sending `GET` requests even if I don't press enter, and that was causing events to be created. Thanks for your answer though, it was exactly what I needed and it explained a bunch of things I didn't know about Associations! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Normally i would use the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in the models. And then use the `.build` method to save them in the create action.

Here some links that might help you:
[Association Methods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) and [Rails Casts: Nested Forms](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) (It's a good explanation about the accepts_nested_attributes_for method.)

Hope it helps